# shape connected with multiple lines with different width in android opengl es10

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've a number of points fetched from the web service. Also there fetched the line joining the co-ordinates. I can create shape by joining these points. but my problem is I need to join these points with different different width. example ;
say I have a points like

**p1**(1f,1f,0f), **p2**(2f,1f,0f), **p3**(3f,1f,0f), **p4**(2f,2f,0f), **p5**(1f,3f,0f), **p6**(3f,2f,0f)... and so on...

now I have to join say 
**Line1** is (p1,p2)
**Line2** is (p2,p3)
**Line3** is(p1,p4)
 and so on...

I can join these lines in a successful way but the Lines may vary with different width say **Line1** may have width of 10, **Line2** with width 5, **Line3** with width 20 and so on...

I know we can get the width of line with gl.glLineWidth(10);
but it renders every lines with the same radius. but my question is to have line joined with different width.

Comment: When you want them with different width, you have to call a draw command for each line separately.

Comment: If you dont mind could you help me with some example. I am completely newbie in opengl android